# Adding DataFrame.from_records to existing df

Tags: python, pandas

I've been pulling data with the requests module to get some data from a website. To put the data into a DataFrame I have been using DataFrame.from_records.

Everything is working fine until I try to append the data to an existing DataFrame. I have tried append, join and merge methods but, I have been having some difficulty.

Since I am limited to the numbers of items I can pull with my API request I want to be able to append it to an existing DataFrame multiple times but, when I run my script it only appends the data *once* despite that I have completely new data from the request "after I rerun the script".

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You better append all df's to a list and then use `pd.concat` once

Comment: Okay, I'll try that next. Could I also potentially use f strings here? That was the next thing I was going to try.

Comment: Too few information to answer regarding f-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, converting my comment to an answer. If you are retrieving your data in a loop due to API limitation, first check whether it is possible to concatenate data or collect it into list, and only convert it to a DataFrame at the end. If that is not possible, do create DataFrames on each call, but collect them into list, and then use `pd.concat` to get concatenate that list of DataFrames into single, final DataFrame. Modifying existing DataFrame on each step of the loop via merging, appending or such, will create unnecessary complexity and slow down the program.

```
out = []
API_CALLS = 10

for i in range(API_CALLS):
    # Your API call here
    dat = call_api()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dat)
    out.append(df)

df = pd.concat(out)
```

Hope this helps, SO question should have full life-cycle, and should be closed at some point. Please open a new question on `f-strings` if you haven't solved it yet.